# Unable to import csv file to python using the pd.read_csv command

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to read a csv file in Python 3.5 having imported pandas using the pd.read_csv command.  However the system returns the following error message:

```
>>> Lung = pd.read_csv('c:\users\LungCapData.csv')
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

In the above error message the left parenthesis is highlighted. 
Could you help me resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following:

```
Lung = pd.read_csv(r'c:\users\LungCapData.csv', sep=';')
```

this should split the columns seeing as you seem to have semi-colons as separators.

Comment: I think the trick is to use `r'c:\...'` instead of OPs `c:\users...` - which is interpreted as a unicode: `\u<number>` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try prefix the string with r  `Lung = pd.read_csv(r'c:\users\LungCapData.csv')`

Comment: This does not work.  The data are all imported (with semi columns in between) in one column.  The resulting dataframe has only one column.

Answer (score 0):

not familiar with windows platform ,but you can try this with encoding option:

```
Lung = pd.read_csv(r'c:\users\LungCapData.csv', encoding="utf8")
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows platform, backslash in the filename string is treated as a delimiter. Use double backslash instead of single backslash, in order to escape the delimiter properly in a string:

```
Lung = pd.read_csv('c:\\users\\LungCapData.csv')
```

On windows 'rb', 'wb' and 'ab' should be used to open a binary file in read, write and append mode respectively.